# Global $http.get() that updates every 5 seconds across all scopes/controllers in Angular 1.5

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-service

In my Angular project I am loading json list from my api that is constantly updating. I would like to have this update every 5 seconds across all my angular controllers without making a new request per controller.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why not just have a service make the API call on an `$interval`, then `$broadcast` a message and the data each time the promise with updated data is fulfilled.

```
angular.module('app')
  .service('PollingService', ['$http', '$rootScope', '$interval', function($http, $rootScope, $interval) {

    var updatedData;

    $interval(function() {
      return $http.get(apiUrl).then(function successCallback(response) {
        updatedData = response.data.data;
        $rootScope.$broadcast('got new data!', { data: updatedData });
      }, function failureCallback(reason) {
        console.log(reason);
      })
    }, 5000);

  }]);
```

And then listen for the broadcast in all the controllers that need the updated data:

```
angular.module('app')
  .controller('someCtrl', ['$scope', function($scope) {

    $scope.$on('got new data!', function(event, args) {
      $scope.data = args.data;
    });

  }]);
```

Comment: I just scratching a solution to get some "unreaded notifications" service and i think this solution fits perfectly, my doubt is: where i should "call" the PollingSerice? Should i call this on app startup (run state) ?

Comment: You can call it in the `app.run` block, or if you have a component that will display the notification to the user, you could wait to call it when that component is initialized. You can pretty much call it wherever you want, since it's just a matter of injecting the `PollingService` where you need it.